# Run JAX-WS Soap Service on WebSphere 8.5

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, websphere-8

I need to deploy a Soap Web Service on my WebSphere 8.5 web application but it seems the IBM application server has some issues with third party ws dependecies.

I added these in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.6</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>xerces</groupId>
       <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this in my web.xml file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And I wrote the sun-jaxws.xml defining the endpoint name and the location of the web service. When running the project I get this error on Eclipse:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager
```

I checked the project and I only found a WebSphere implementation of the CatalogManager, so I don't know if what I need to do is make the project point to this CatalogManager or maybe I'm just messing up something else.

Comment: You typically want to use the JAX-WS support built into WAS, rather than packaging an external implementation. Is there a reason you can't do this? If you do need to, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

Comment: Many dev teams prefer their applications / jaxws to work in/out of websphere -- so they can develop with springboot / tomcat , and deploy in webpsphere (e.g due to company restriction).